# Java equivalent to Ruby's SecureRandom?

Tags: java, security, encryption, ruby

Is there a Java equivalent to [Ruby's `SecureRandom.hex(...)`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) method?

Happy with anything in JVM-land:

- Something living inside the Java crypto APIs
- Something provided by a 3rd party/open source library
- Even anything written in another JVM language (Groovy/Scala/Kotlin/etc.) that can be pulled in as a compiled jar

Basically I just need the ability to generate a random 32-bit key from inside Java code (which would have the same effect if I was using this Ruby method via `SecureRandom.hex(32)`). **Any ideas?**

I *did* try:

```
// import java.security.SecureRandom
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
byte[] len = new byte[32];
System.out.println("key = " + sr.nextBytes(len));
```

but it spits out `key = null`...

Comment: Um, the most obvious thing to try would be JRuby, no? (Note that I use neither Ruby nor JRuby, so my intuition may be very naive on this matter.)

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
Integer.toHexString(
    new SecureRandom().nextInt()
)
```

> bd594090

## JRuby

Run your [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)) code on a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) with [JRuby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRuby).

## `java.security.SecureRandom`

Java includes [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#next-int-), a cryptographically strong random number generator (RNG).

Pass the number of bits to be generated, right justified, with leading zeros.

```
int x = new SecureRandom().nextInt() ;
```

> 1286623117

To generate a hex string, pass that `int` to `Integer.toHexString`.

```
String output = Integer.toHexString( x ) ;  // And maybe call `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase` as you desire.
```

> 4cb04f8d

## Extract from UUID Version 4

A [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is a 128-bit value designed to be used as a universally-unique identifier. Originally specified as a point in time  and space, combining the current moment with a [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) plus an arbitrary number.

Later [Version 4 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) was defined to randomly generate 122 of the 128 bits.  The [`java.util.UUID`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) class in Java promises to use a cryptographically-strong pseudo-random number generator.

The canonical expression of a UUID is 32 hex characters with 4 hyphens. So if take such a string, remove the hyphens, we can take hex characters at the leading end  as the non-random 4 bits are in the second half of the hex string.

For your 32-bit hex value, we need 1/4 of the hex characters (1/4 of 128 bits = 32 bits), or the first 8 hex characters.

```
String hex = 
    java.util.UUID
    .randomUUID()
    .toString()
    .replace( "-" , "" )  // Remove hyphens, leaving only hex characters.
    .substring( 0 , 8 )   // Annoying zero-based counting. 
;
```

The [UUID standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Standards) require the hex string to be lowercase, though many implementation violate this rule. Either way, you should make  call to enforce your own choice of uppercase or lowercase hex.

```
String hex = 
    java.util.UUID
    .randomUUID()
    .toString()
    .replace( "-" , "" )  // Remove hyphens, leaving only hex characters.
    .substring( 0 , 8 )   // Annoying zero-based counting. 
    .toLowerCase()        // Or `toUpperCase` as you desire.
;
```

## Use entire UUID

If your purpose is to generate distinct values as identifiers, consider using the entir [universally unique identifier (UUID)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID)  value discussed above.

Version 1 UUIDs are best, but if unavailable you can fall back to using Version 4. That is good enough for many purposes.

In Java, see the [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class.

Comment: `SecureRandom#next` method is protected, so, unfortunately, that can't be used out of the box. This might do something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622622/generating-a-random-hex-string-of-length-50-in-java-me-j2me